# Nginx case-insensitive location with case-sensitive proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, proxy

We've got several locations with reverse proxies setup. Our current config up and running is:

```
upstream backends {
    server Backend1;
    server Backend2;
}

server {
    ... other server config stuff here ...

    location /App1 {
        ... proxy header stuff ...

        proxy_pass http://backends/App1;
     }
}
```

Now what we're trying to do is set it up such that the case-sensitive backends (in this case Backend1/2 http://backends/App1) can be case insensitive to the public such that you can access http://example.com/app1 OR http://example.com/App1 (or any variation of)

Our new config that we're trying to get to work is something like:

```
location ~* /App1 {
    proxy_pass http://backends/App1;
}
```

But no dice when we reload the config. We're seeing the error:

> "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular
>   expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or
>   inside "limit_except"...

Any thoughts/insight on how we can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implicit rewrite performed by `proxy_pass` will not work in the presence of a regular expression location. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for more.

However, you can use a `rewrite ... break` to perform the same function.

```
location ~* /App1(?<stuff>.*)$ {
    rewrite ^ /App1$stuff break;
    proxy_pass http://backends;
}
```

The regular expression is extended with a named capture to grab the remainder of the URI, then the `rewrite` statement builds a new URI for passing upstream.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: Thank you! I tried various other configs with a rewrite rule in there but with no success. Just didn't have the right combo of elements in the rule.